# Synchronizing port numbers of two simulink models

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have two simulink models with same port name but has different port number , because the way copy and paste was done .
I am trying to synchroize the port numbers (in order to have same port number) in both the models

model1.slx

[image: Model Data Model1.slx]

model2.slx

[image: Model Data Model2.slx]

I can manually change the numbers by the editor but there are lot of signals.
Is their any faster way to synchronize the data

Comment: You can change port number of a port using set_param(blkPath, 'Port','<num>'); You would need to write a script to make your port numbers match.

Comment: Consider using Simulink Buses instead of huge number of Inports. This will be easier to manage and allow models to share the same input bus data type.